# Flutter - ListView.builder() not working after the JSON fetch

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to load the JSON from a local variable in my class file and convert the JSON to a list of objects using PODO class but I don't know why the list isn't getting generated. I am so much frustrated. Please help me where I am doing wrong.

I have tried every possible way by manipulating the code, even the same code works for a different JSON format with its PODO class.

Thank you.

Flutter class source code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Demo createState() => _Demo();
}

class _Demo extends State<Demo> {
  final localJson = '''
      [
        {
            "message": "Some message here 1"
        },
        {
            "message": "Some message here 2"
        },
        {
            "message": "Some message here 3"
        }
      ]
      ''';

  Widget getCommentItem({@required PodoClass item}) {
    return Text(item.message);
  }

  Future<List<PodoClass>> fetchComments() async {
    return compute(parseJson, localJson);
  }

  List<PodoClass> parseJson(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

    return parsed.map<PodoClass>((json) => PodoClass.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  Widget _bodyBuild({@required List<PodoClass> items}) {
    return ListView.builder(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          return getCommentItem(item: items[index]);
        });
  }

  Widget body() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<PodoClass>>(
      future: fetchComments(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

        return snapshot.hasData
            ? _bodyBuild(items: snapshot.data)
            : Center(child: Text('Loading..'));
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: false,
            title: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Comments",
                  ),
                  Text("Battle ID", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12))
                ])),
        body: body());
  }
}

// podo class
class PodoClass {
  String message;

  PodoClass({this.message});

  PodoClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    message = json['message'];
  }
}
```

Comment: I see you are using a method called `compute()`. What is that method doing?
The best way to solve your problem is to print the values of your array at the entry and at the exit of each method.
In this way, you isolate the steps used to build your list and probably find the problem.

Comment: @AndreiCaisim The compute() function runs expensive functions in a background isolate and returns the result. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must move `parseJson` function outside the class
it should be top level function

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html

> The callback argument must be a top-level function, not a closure or
>   an instance or static method of a class.

Comment: Oh great. Thank you. An extra thank you for the explanation. <3

Answer (score 0):

The **compute** does not work in this case, simply call the function.
*I've included a delay which may help you with testing.*

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Demo createState() => _Demo();
}

class _Demo extends State<Demo> {
  final localJson = '''
        [
          {
              "message": "Some message here 1"
          },
          {
              "message": "Some message here 2"
          },
          {
              "message": "Some message here 3"
          }
        ]
        ''';

  Widget getCommentItem({@required PodoClass item}) {
    return Text(item.message);
  }

  Future<List<PodoClass>> fetchComments() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    return parseJson(localJson);
  }

  List<PodoClass> parseJson(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

    return parsed.map<PodoClass>((json) => PodoClass.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  Widget _bodyBuild({@required List<PodoClass> items}) {
    return ListView.builder(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          return getCommentItem(item: items[index]);
        });
  }

  Widget body() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<PodoClass>>(
      future: fetchComments(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);

        return snapshot.hasData
            ? _bodyBuild(items: snapshot.data)
            : Center(child: Text('Loading..'));
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: false,
            title: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Comments",
                  ),
                  Text("Battle ID", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12))
                ])),
        body: body());
  }
}

// podo class
class PodoClass {
  String message;

  PodoClass({this.message});

  PodoClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    message = json['message'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but that's not the correct way to computing JSON, think if the JSON is so complex and larget, 5 seconds would be so less.

As answered by ``Eugene``, the solution is great.